# searching an array of arrays with multiple or single values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript array, in which I need to return the matching city names.

```
[['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne']]
```

When input is 634, the javascript function will return Toulouse.
When input is '634,75', then the return will be a list of comma separated cities. 'Toulouse, Paris'
When input is '634,75,668' then the return will be a list of comma separated cities. 'Toulouse, Paris, Lyon'

Any ideas?

UPDATE : Multiple ids are coming in as comma separated list : '634,75,668' : doing a id[0].split(',') seems to work with the map.

Comment: There is plenty of solutions. But if you have to deal with very long array of cities, and many searches live, I strongly suggest you to transform your data in Key => Value first `{ '634': 'Toulouse', ... }, and then process the matching on IDs. This way repeated searches will find cities instantly with 0(1) time complexity.

Comment: added real test case with `<input >` to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Map to allow for fast lookups, and then map from the ids to the data in the Map.

```js
const data = [['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne']];

function lookup(data, ...ids) {
  let dataMap = new Map(data)
  return ids.map(id => dataMap.get(id)).join(', ')
}

console.log(lookup(data, ...['634', '75']))
console.log(lookup(data, ...'634,75'.split(',')))
```

Comment: Not sure what ."..ids" mean.  Also, data object will need to passed into the lookup function.

Comment: @KFNinja, `...ids` uses [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Whether you pass `data` as argument to the function or not, is a choice you could make, but not relevant for your question, in my opinion. This is the right answer.

Comment: very slow on bigger data, no sense to convert the input to an object

Comment: @KFNinja I've updated it so that you can pass in the data as a parameter

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev thanks, you're right, I've switched out Object.fromEntries for new Map(), which increases performance, especially if there are multiple ids being looked up and if the number of cities is around 36k (the approximate number of cities in France).

Comment: looks better indeed

Comment: @AndrewParks My IDs  are coming as a comma separated list. '634,75,668'

Comment: @KFNinja do you mean a string, or a javascript array? I've updated the answer to handle both

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an efficient algorithm O(k) + O(n) you could create a map of indices of the input ids and scan the city array only once and construct the final array.

You can cache city lookups to make all consecutive calls faster. That's opposed to Andrew Parks' solution where all cities are cached at the start, it could introduce unwanted load & a memory bite on a page load plus what sense on caching all cities especially with a big list.

```js
const cityData = [['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne']];
const cache = {};

function findCities(...inputNumbers) {
  const map = {};
  const result = Array(inputNumbers.length);
  inputNumbers.forEach((n, i) => cache[n] ? result[i] = cache[n] : map[n] = i + 1); 
  let count = 0;
  for(const c of cityData){
    const idx = map[c[0]];
    if(idx){
     result[idx - 1] = cache[c[0]] = c[1];
     if(++count === inputNumbers.length) break;
    }
  }
  return result.join(', ');
}

function updateCities(value){
  const cities = value.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).filter(Boolean);
  $cities.textContent = findCities(...cities); 
}

console.log(findCities('634')); 
console.log(findCities('634', '75')); 
console.log(findCities('634', '75', '668'));
```

```html
<input oninput="updateCities(this.value)">
<div id="$cities"></div>
```

```
` Chrome/122
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                         n=100      |     n=1000      |    n=10000     |    n=100000   
Alexander            1.44x x100k 111 | 1.00x x100k 789 | 1.00x x10k 781 | 1.00x x100 131
Andrew Parks         3.39x x100k 261 | 3.57x  x10k 282 | 4.25x  x1k 332 | 1.42x x100 186
Selaka Nanayakkara   1.00x   x1m 770 | 1.71x  x10k 135 | 4.44x  x1k 347 | 2.70x x100 354
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let $length = 100;
const cityData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array.from({length: $length}, () => [Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6), 'NoCity']).concat([['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne'], ['111', 'Test city'], ['222', 'Test city 2']])));
function test(fn){
  return fn('634', '75', '668', '111', '222');
}

// @benchmark Alexander
test(function (...inputNumbers) {
  const map = {};
  inputNumbers.forEach((n, i) => map[n] = i + 1); 
  const result = Array(inputNumbers.length);
  let count = 0;
  for(const c of cityData){
    const idx = map[c[0]];
    if(idx){
     result[idx - 1] = c[1];
     if(++count === inputNumbers.length) break;
    }
  }
  return result.join(', ');
})

// @benchmark Andrew Parks
test(function(...ids){
  let dataMap = new Map(cityData)
  return ids.map(id => dataMap.get(id)).join(', ')
});

// @benchmark Selaka Nanayakkara
test(function (...inputNumbers) {
  const matchingCities = [];
  inputNumbers.forEach((number) => {
    const city = cityData.find((entry) => entry[0] === number);
    if (city) {
      matchingCities.push(city[1]);
    }
  });
  return matchingCities.join(', ');
})

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.find()` method to search for a matching city for each input number. If a match is found, it adds the corresponding city name to the `matchingCities` array. Then you can join to create a comma-separated string of the matching cities.

```js
const cityData = [['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne']];

function findCities(...inputNumbers) {
  const matchingCities = [];
  inputNumbers.forEach((number) => {
    const city = cityData.find((entry) => entry[0] === number);
    if (city) {
      matchingCities.push(city[1]);
    }
  });
  return matchingCities.join(', ');
}


console.log(findCities('634')); 
console.log(findCities('634', '75')); 
console.log(findCities('634', '75', '668'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If we first convert the array into an object (once), we can write a function based on that object as follows:

```js
const arr = [['75', 'Paris'], ['456', 'Marseille'], ['634', 'Toulouse'], ['668', 'Lyon'], ['035', 'Saint-Étienne']];
const obj = arr.reduce( (acc, cur) => ({...acc,[cur[0]]:cur[1]}), {} );
const getCities = ( o, ...c ) => c.map(id => o[id]).join(', ');

console.log( getCities( obj, 634 ) );
console.log( getCities( obj, 634, 75 ) );
console.log( getCities( obj, 634, 75, 668 ) );
```